# How to put an icon to the title of an input widget in Shiny and Shiny dashboard

Tags: html, r, shiny, font-awesome, shinydashboard

Is it possible to add an icon to the title of an input widget in Shiny and Shiny and Shiny dashboard? Below is an example. I want to add an icon to each input widget to indicate if it is a numeric input (using a bar-chart icon) or a text input (using a font icon). For now, I am using two columns. One with `width = 1` for the icon, and the other is for the input widget. It would be great if I can add the icon to the title directly. Please let me know if there are ways to achieve this.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Icon Example"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(
      text = "Input",
      tabName = "Input"
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItem(
    tabName = "Input",
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 6,
        box(
          status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
          width = 12,
          title = "Box 1",
          fluidRow(
            column(width = 1,
                   tags$div(HTML('<i class="fa fa-bar-chart" style = "color:#0072B2;"></i>'))
            ),
            column(width = 11,
                   numericInput(inputId = "Num", label = "This is a numeric input", value = 1000))
          ),
          fluidRow(
            column(width = 1,
                   tags$div(HTML('<i class="fa fa-font" style = "color:#D55E00;"></i>'))
            ),
            column(width = 11,
                   textInput(inputId = "Text", label = "This is a text input")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# User Interface
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = header,
  sidebar = sidebar,
  body = body
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session){}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is a screenshot of my code example. I would like to have the beginning of the input field aligned with the icon (as indicated by the red arrows). In other words, I hope the icon can be part of the title of the input widget.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit:**

To increase the readability of the code we can use `icon` instead of `HTML`:

```
numericInput(inputId = "Num", label = div(icon("bar-chart", style = "color:blue;"), " This is a numeric input"), value = 1000)
```

---

**Initial answer:**

Just use your `div` as the label:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Icon Example")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem(text = "Input", tabName = "Input")))

body <- dashboardBody(tabItem(tabName = "Input",
                              fluidRow(column(
                                width = 6,
                                box(
                                  status = "primary",
                                  solidHeader = TRUE,
                                  width = 12,
                                  title = "Box 1",
                                  fluidRow(column(
                                    width = 11,
                                    numericInput(
                                      inputId = "Num",
                                      label = tags$div(HTML('<i class="fa fa-bar-chart" style = "color:#0072B2;"></i> This is a numeric input')),
                                      value = 1000
                                      )
                                  )),
                                  fluidRow(column(
                                    width = 11,
                                    textInput(
                                      inputId = "Text",
                                      label = tags$div(HTML('<i class="fa fa-font" style = "color:#D55E00;"></i> This is a text input'))
                                      )
                                  ))
                                )
                              ))))

# User Interface
ui <- dashboardPage(header = header,
                    sidebar = sidebar,
                    body = body)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is great.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by wrapping `icon()` to `span()` and `tagList()`. Check the updated code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Icon Example"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(
      text = "Input",
      tabName = "Input"
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItem(
    tabName = "Input",
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 6,
        box(
          status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
          width = 12,
          title = span(tagList(icon("bar-chart"), "Box 1")),
          fluidRow(
            column(width = 1,
                   tags$div(HTML('<i class="fa fa-bar-chart" style = "color:#0072B2;"></i>'))
            ),
            column(width = 11,
                   numericInput(inputId = "Num", label = "This is a numeric input", value = 1000))
          )
        ),

        box(
          status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
          width = 12,
          title = span(tagList(icon("font"), "Box 2")),
          fluidRow(
            column(width = 1,
                   tags$div(HTML('<i class="fa fa-font" style = "color:#D55E00;"></i>'))
            ),
            column(width = 11,
                   textInput(inputId = "Text", label = "This is a text input")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# User Interface
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = header,
  sidebar = sidebar,
  body = body
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session){}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not what I am looking for (Nevertheless, I give you an upvote because it is cool to show how to use `span` and `tagList`). Please see my updated screenshot and description of my question. I want to put the icon as part of the title of the input widget.